# jhipster v4.14.4 - building an executable WAR-file

Tags: spring, docker, jhipster

As mentioned [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/production/) as well as [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/) it should be possible - and a must-have for the docker-container - to be able to build a WAR-file of the whole application with `./gradlew -Pprod bootWar` or make the application ready for a deployment via docker-container with `./gradlew bootWar -Pprod buildDocker`.

But Intellij IDEA tells me, that there is no task `bootWar`. And `./gradlew -Pprod bootRun`doesn't generate a `*.war`-file in `build/libs/`.

I also tried publishing directly to heroku, triggered by pushes to my github-repository controlled by a local jenkins2 docker-container. Maybe even the 404-Site after successful builds at heroku comes from this. The manual way documented in the [jhipster.tech-documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/heroku/) with `./gradlew -Pprod bootWar -x test` and `heroku deploy:jar --jar build/libs/*war` can't work without the *.war.

So how can I export my monolithic jhipster-application into a `*.war`-file?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can generate a war with gradle by typing the following command

`./gradlew -P prod build` and/or `./gradlew -P prod build bootRepackage`

Comment: and how can I build and deploy the images (mysql, hazelcast, elasticsearch and my app) together with docker? I am not able to understand how the defined *.yml-files from jhipster will work together.

Comment: The yaml files are for docker and, they don't related to the created image itself. You can use that to start everything using compose. See the docker-compose sub generator for details. But as mentioned (and tested) "gradlew build' generates a war file